# Passing unix shell (optional) text parameter without expansion

Tags: linux, unix, shell, posix

I want to write a unix/linux script `updategit.sh` with a default parameter to commit to git. `updategit.sh` should be POSIX compatible. I hope POSIX will solves some of worst incompatibilities of the unix/linux shells.

Syntax: `updategit.sh {$1}`

`{$1}` means the parameter `$1` is optional.

1) If no parameter is passed to `updategit.sh` the last action in the script should be:

```
git commit -m 'Patches #1023, #1016.4 .. .17 reapplied. See e-mail from Paul (paul@sh.ts) send at 2016-01-26 08:56'
```

Is it enough to pass it in single quotes when the text does not contain a single quote?

2) It should be possible to pass an optional parameter `$1` to `updategit.sh`. The natural syntax would be to enclose the parameter in double quotes. I think that will not be possible. I want to able to get as much as possible to `updategit.sh` without the shell destroying the input parameter and the command to fail because of the shell messing with the input.

The natural syntax would be something like this:

```
$ ./updategit.sh "New template GetShape()"
$ ./updategit.sh "Patch #312.5 applied. See Eve's email (eve@stoneage.nix) from 2016-02.29 09:43"
$ ./updategit.sh "Round to .5 fixed"
$ ./updategit.sh
```

It is clear that the shell will mess with input. How near could I come to the "natural" syntax without `git commit -m $1` to fail? AFAIK the command `git commit -m $1` must be rewritten to something more robust.

Answer (score 1):

Technically all arguments to shell scripts are optional. It's up to the script to determine if there are missing arguments and what to do about it. This can be done in several ways depending on your needs. For a script that has only one argument which is optional, something like this would work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
if [ ${#1} -eq 0 ]
then
    git commit -m "default message"
else
    git commit -m "$1"
fi
```

This checks if the length of the first argument is zero and acts accordingly. If the first argument is missing, it counts as having zero length. You could also check against number of arguments by comparing against `$#`.

A shorter variation of the above script, which takes advantage of empty argument substitution, is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
git commit -m "${1:-default message}"
```

This sort of thing is described [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) under "2.6.2 Parameter Expansion".

Comment: A simpler version would be `if [ ! "$1" ]`. Pay attention to the whitespace around `[` and `]` – it's a _command_, not some magic language syntax.

Comment: @grawity Fixed...